# How to schedule events in PHP

Tags: php, sql, events, calendar, scheduling

I am creating a processing system in PHP, I read tons of tutorials over the internet but nothing
seems to satisfy what I need for my system.

I have table SCHEDULE in SQL..

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| ID | Name |     Description     |
+----+------+---------------------+
|    |      |                     |
|  1 | D    | Daily               |
|  2 | W    | Weekends            |
|  3 | EOM  | End Of the month    |
|  4 | 11d  | 11 day of the month |
|  5 | M    | Monday              |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

And Table PROCESS..

```
+----+---------------+-----------+
| ID | Schedule_id   |   Name    | 
+----+---------------+-----------+
|  1 |             1 | Process 1 | 
|  2 |             2 | Process 2 | 
|  3 |             3 | Process 3 |  
+----+---------------+-----------+
```

What I want is to automatically show the process on each days base on their schedule.

Meaning:

**if  Process1 = D RUN Process1 everyday**

**if Process2 = W   RUN ONLY Process2 on weekends**

**if Process3 = 11d RUN ONLY Process3 on the 11th day of the month**

I also want them to store on my calendar and also how about holidays? 
All answers will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Building the php code, a query, how to run the query on that specific day? In the current format this question is too broad.

Comment: Yeah also read about that. But i fee like there is much more easier way to code this system

Comment: @Sean php code and query

Comment: Have you attempted any code? The purpose of SO is to help, not write code for you. Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

I understand that activities **don't** have an associated schedule, so you can be at any given time. Taking that as a starting point, you can run a cronjob, every day, through a script in PHP which being entrusted to compare the tasks that the day should be made and there using shell_exec() php function to run the process in bash or in what you have defined.

That is:

- For each record in "sheduled" you compare the date (If today, tomorrow or the weekend) and if there is a match, run the associated process.